# Issue with `libz.so.1` when running PhantomJS

Tags: kali-linux, symlink, shared-library, javascript

After extracting the file contents from the `phantomjs` archive, I ran the command `phantomjs` and was met with the error:

```
phantomjs: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have searched online for solutions, but the problem still persists. I have updated the dynamic linker cache with `ldconfig`. I have updated the library path with:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I have even deleted the symbolic link `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1` and recreated it pointing to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.3`. Also, the latest version of `zlib1g-dev` is already installed (1:1.3.dfsg-3+b1).

If the solutions above did not resolve the issue, then what other solution could there be?

Comment: "the phantomjs archive": You will have to tell us exactly what file that is. Anyways, what you show simply tells us that you're trying to use a binary that's incompatible with the software on your system.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, from `https://phantomjs.org/download.html`, I downloaded the archive file for linux: `phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-i686.tar.bz2 `.

Comment: are you really on a 32 bit machine?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, no. I am also using WSL2 (Kali), now supporting systemd.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to use Kali (from `https://www.kali.org`: __Kali Linux__ is an open-source, Debian-based Linux security distribution geared towards various information tasks, such as Penetration Testing, Security Research, Computer Forensics and Reverse Engineering. ) as a general purpose Linux system. This is unwise. Rather, install a supported Ubuntu release. You can build or install any of the Kali tools.

Comment: @Maestro you're using a 32 bit version of the (dead?) software on a 64 bit system that doesn't ship 32 bit libraries can't work. Also, no sense in using Kali for this, as Waltinator says.

Comment: I realize the mistake that I made. I simply wasn't paying attention on the downloads page for phantomjs. Also, I am new to bug bounty hunting and will need phantoms as an alternative to curl for certain situations like testing sites for DOM XSS vulnerabilities and the like. I do not intend to use Kali as a general purpose linux system; that's what I have suse linux for. Still new to linux and all of its various flavors. Anyways, thank you two for your help and advice.

Comment: for anything that you do on your computer over the internet, you don't need Kali at all; any (unlike Kali) general-purpose Linux will do. Actually, will do better, because unlike Kali, other Linux distros are meant to make accessing networks easy, not to be covert in a hostile network environment you're in. Different use cases. You're using the wrong distro.